# Firebase Android / iOS Cache Firestore Collection

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to cache aa complete collection to offline use?

I want to implement a offline in a new app, we are using Firebase Firestore and we want to know if there is a way to cache a whole collection.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we want to know if there is a way to cache a whole collection.

No, there is no way you can cache only a single collection. It's the entire database or nothing. The cache includes all collections and subcollection within your entire database. You cannot tell Firestore to cache only a single collection and ignore the other once.

Comment: I mean,  i want to download and cache a whole collections in some point and use it after a while (in offline mode)

Comment: You cannot download and cache a single collection for a future use. On user's device will permanently exist the entire Firestore database which contains all collections. If your database it is composed only from a singe collection, then in your cache you'll have only one collection.

Comment: Are you saying that when the offline mode in active all the database is downloaded to de cache? , ,All the data base (Firestore)

Comment: Yes, that's right. As an example, if you have two collections (`collectionOne` and `collectionTwo`), both containing 100 documents and you are making a `get()` call on both of them, your local cache will contain a total of 200 documents. Unfortunately, you cannot say, hey Firestore, I only want in my cache documents from `collectionOne` **but** not from `collectionTwo`. Is it clear now?